# Cutting a square into non-similar triangles

Tags: triangles, plane-geometry, triangulation, dissection

> Is it possible to cut a square into an infinite number of triangles, so that all of them are non-similar?

Comment: Never received a faster downvote.

Comment: The downvote is most likely due to the total lack of context. Where does this problem come from? Why do you care about solving it? Have you already tried to solve it?

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter I just created this problem and decided to ask here. Is that something I should not do?

Comment: This is a good question, but you have to show what work you've done!  If you've actually put effort into finding an answer, then I'm sure many people would love to help.

Comment: @Shalom This isn't a place to post puzzles or try to stump people, it's for helping people solve problems that they're stuck on. If you haven't even attempted to answer your own question, you can't be stuck.

Comment: I disagree with all of you. Because creativity both in answering and creating your own questions should be rewarded. There is no reason why we all should not try to create new problems and ask here for solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Do it with four congruent isosceles triangles first, in very different ways (three of them can be finitely cut). A square is the union of four of them.

[image]

Comment: He was asking about an infinite amount of non-similar triangles.  Four isosceles triangles is very much a finite amount of triangles.

Comment: I mean cut up the isoceles triangles.